# What's a "natural" way to show that, for unital channels, $\Phi(X)=X$ iff $[X,A_a]=0$ for all Kraus operators $A_a$?

Tags: quantum-operation, kraus-representation

This is a statement proved in Watrous, Theorem 4.25, page 229 of [the online version](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ewatrous/TQI).

Let $\Phi\in\mathrm C(\mathcal X)$ be a unital channel with Kraus representation $\Phi(X)=\sum_a A_a X A_a^\dagger$. Then for any linear operator $X\in\mathrm{Lin}(\mathcal X)$, a linear operator $X$ is a fixed point for $\Phi$ iff it commutes with all Kraus operators:
$$\Phi(X)=X\iff [X,A_a]=0\,\,\forall a.$$

To prove this, the author defines the operators $C_a\equiv [X,A_a]$ and then $C\equiv \sum_a C_a C_a^\dagger$, and observe that, assuming $\Phi(X)=X$, we have
$$\Phi(C) = \sum_a (XA_a-A_a X)(A_a^\dagger X^\dagger - X^\dagger A_a^\dagger)
\\= X\Phi(I)X^\dagger 
 - X \Phi(X^\dagger) - \Phi(X)X^\dagger + \Phi(XX^\dagger)
 = \Phi(XX^\dagger) - XX^\dagger.$$
Because $\Phi$ is trace-preserving, this implies that $\operatorname{Tr}(C)=\operatorname{Tr}(\Phi(C))=0$, and thus $C=0$, which in turn implies $C_a=[X,A_a]=0$.

This all works and is relatively straightforward, but leaves me wondering where the idea of using such operators came from. Why test the action of $\Phi$ on these particular operators $C$? Is there any intuition to it? Different routes to the result would also be interesting.

For example $\Phi(X)=X$ is equivalent to $\operatorname{vec}(X)$ being an eigenvector $K(\Phi)=\sum_a A_a\otimes \bar A_a$ (natural representation). If there was a nice way to see how the "unitality" of $\Phi$ is reflected in the structure of the Kraus operators (aside from them satisfying $\sum_a A_a A_a^\dagger=I$), maybe this could offer another way to see why $\sum_a (A_a\otimes\bar A_a)\operatorname{vec}(X)= \operatorname{vec}(X)$ should imply $[X,A_a]=0$.

From a different perspective, one could observe that, for a vector $\psi\in\mathcal X$, we have $\Phi(\mathbb P(\psi))=\sum_a \mathbb P(A_a \psi)$, where $\mathbb P(v)\equiv vv^\dagger$. Thus $\psi$ is a fixed point *iff* $A_a\psi$ are all collinear: $A_a\psi=\lambda_a \phi$ for some coefficients $\lambda_a\in\mathbb C$ and fixed $\phi\in\mathcal X$.
This seems like a pretty strong condition, but still, I'm not sure how to convert it to the stated result.

Comment: The title does not reflect your question ...

Comment: Just wanted to comment that asking for a "natural" way to prove it might be more promising, and saw your edit ;)

Comment: @NorbertSchuch guess that depends on your definition of "why", and whether gaining intuition about a proof qualifies? Or are you referring to something else? (replying to the first comment above)

Comment: Well, the first version of your question *did* provide a proof, which is usually what I would associate with a "why is X true" question. (Some more mathematically inclined people might argue that there is nothing to "why" beyond a proof.) Maybe "intuitive proof why ... " would be more to the point?

Comment: You might try to check Michael Wolf's lecture notes, but I suspect he provides the same proof.

Comment: But the proof from the book doesn't test the action of $\Phi$ on $C$. And we don't know that $\Phi(C) = C$ (until we prove it's 0). The proof from the book just rewrites $C$ as $\Phi(XX^\dagger) - XX^\dagger$. And the result follows.

Comment: I hear what you're saying, the proof makes use of a trick and it's natural to wonder where it comes from. The trick appears in a 1999 paper by Goran Lindblad, with the theorem and proof itself appearing more explicitly in a 2003 paper by David Kribs. The proof establishes something quite amazing, which is that the operators fixed by any unital channel always form an algebra. You might find a more direct proof, and I would not want to discourage anyone from searching, but don't look a gift horse in the mouth! This is a proof from the book in my view.

Comment: @JohnWatrous This might be worth an answer, even if only since comments are volatile. -- (Also to OP:) In hindsight, one might of course say that in order to prove that some objects X_i are all zero, it is natural to show that their norm-squared summed is zero, and it is indeed something appearing in quite some proofs, but of course it is easy to say this in hindsight. Though I would argue that this can be seen as a quite natural proof.